# CSS PHP MYSQL Dispaly tag results in 2 columns sorted by postType

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm implementing a tagging system and I'd like to display the results sharing the same tag within a page divided in 2 columns, sorted by postType (article or video), something like this:

```
 ARTICLES            VIDEOS
 article 1           video 1
 article 2           video 2
 article 3           video 3
                     video 4
```

But this is what I get:

```
ARTICLES            VIDEOS
                    video 1
                    video 2
                    video 3
article 1           video 4
article 2
article 3
```

My query:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT p.*
                      FROM tags t
                        INNER JOIN post_tags pt
                            ON t.tagID = pt.tagID
                        INNER JOIN posts p
                            ON pt.postID = p.postID
                        WHERE t.tagName = :tagName
                      ORDER BY postType ASC');
$stmt->execute(array(':tagName' => $row['tagName']));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class=column1">';
        if($row['postType']=='article' {
            ....
        }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class=column2">';
        if($row['postType']=='video' {
            ....
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

The CSS:

```
.column1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
}
.column2 {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

I'm stuck with this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As this is CSS and html can you make a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please check my answer it its help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strArticle = '';
$strVideo = '';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    if($row['postType']=='article') 
    {
        $strArticle .= '<div class="row">Your variable</div>';


    }
    if($row['postType']=='video') 
    {
        $strArticle .= '<div class="row">Your variable</div>';
    }
}
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Article</h4>
    <?php echo $strArticle;?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Video</h4>
    <?php echo $strVideo;?>
</div>
```

Hello please put this code of while loop like this and if you follow bootstrap structure you can do this easily add css to the class col-md-6 to width 50% and class row has width 100%.

In simple first make two column and in each column row wise entry.

Comment: @nacho Welcome by following bootstrap you can easily do this.